# When does equality hold in limsup of product inequality?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

I am trying to find the necessary and sufficient condition that, $$\lim\sup(a_nb_n)=\lim\sup(a_n)\lim\sup(b_n)$$ I know equality takes place if one of them converges,but I want to find a condition both necessary and sufficient.Can someone help me on this?

Comment: The only condition I can think of is supremum of both sequence are uniform in K (in the usual $\epsilon-K$ formulation in sequence). Bu this is just a rephrase of your statement. (provided both sequence are positive, i.e. there is a tail with only non-negative terms). But this is only using basic formulation with basic real analysis definitions. If you are looking for better forms, you have to state clearly what formulations of the statement you prefer, e.g. in integral form, differential form, etc.

Comment: @Kevin Song can you provide any solution to my question?

Comment: @LKMKlein Is there any better condition?

Comment: @KishalaySarkar The condition that you gave in the question is ok. I'm thinking if there exists any other.

Comment: What about, (assuming both sequences are positive), let $a,b$ be $lim sup$ of respective sequence, and if $limsup$ of $\{ab_n\}$ equals that of $limsup$ of $\{ a_n b_n \}$, then this equality holds. (This is another rephrase of the statement I made)

Comment: Well, just imagine neither $\lim(a_n)$ nor $\lim(b_n)$ is defined, which means they are periodic, then the equality no longer holds. @KishalaySarkar

Comment: @KishalaySarkar The situation mentioned by LKM Klein may be an answer to your question. If you want that equality holds for other conditions, then we need to restrict the relationship between the two sequences.

Comment: @KevinSong I am looking for a NASC condition...